# Selecting the Nth record in a SQL dataset

Tags: sql, vb.net, ole

Lets say I have a dataset with I dunno 20 records in it.

How do I get to the 16th record in the dataset or the Nth? So any number from 1 to 20

I have spent most of this week trying to think of a method and so far I have gotten no where.

I want the 16th record down in this dataset and there doesn't seem to be a specific command for it.

I'm working in VB.NET with OLE commands.

I'm not sure any code would be of any use to help solve this but I'm populating the dataset something like this:

```
SQL_Str = "SELECT FROM A TABLE WHERE CRITERIA IS MET"
dbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL_Str, dbConnector)
dbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet, "SelectedRecords")
```

Now what do I do to get to the 16th row in this dataset knowing that there is 20 records in the dataset?

Comment: The solution can be SQL dependent... which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server/Mysql/etc?

Comment: I am using ADOX to create an Access database then using OLEDB to control that database

Comment: How do you determine the `N`th? SQL does not guarantee any specific order if you do not explicitly state one!

Comment: I want to give users the ability to state one which can be used, that is why I wanted to say Nth

Comment: This might help.  http://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/ranking-in-ms-access/

Comment: I don't need to rank the data in the dataset in any way, I just want to select for example the 16th record in the dataset.

Comment: @user2177940 once you've ranked it you can then select the one of a certain rank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you are using VB.NET, just read the row from the dataSet.

```
Private Function GetRow(ByVal ds As Data.DataSet, ByVal rowNum As Integer) As Data.DataRow
  Dim result As Data.DataRow = Nothing
  Dim table As Data.DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
  result = table.Rows(rowNum)
  Return result
End Function
```

There are overloads to `DataSet.Tables`: Consider:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where you've said db.Tables(0), could the 0 be switched for the name of the table in the dataset?

Comment: @user2177940 [Yes see the DataTableCollection.Item property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58st33fb(v=vs.110).aspx) but you should probably use a DataView with its sort property set or add an ORDER By to the original sql if you want deterministic results

Comment: I've updated with a screenshot showing 3 of 4 overload options.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have made this work with my code. And it works quite well.